# how can I access my server ' sonarqube.xxx.xxx:9200' without the port number

Tags: server, dns, sonarqube, ip, a-records

A little history, sonarqube server is hosted  on ec2 instance.

Have created an A record to point to the domain name.

I have issues pointing both Ipnumber:port to domain name. Hence, I can only access the server via domain-name:port

Answer (score 0):

There is no way to specify a port in a hostname or DNS record.

If you don’t want to include the port number in the URL then run the service on the default port for the type of service (e.g. 443 for HTTPS or 80 for HTTP).